# Using SentenceTransformer embedder as global variable in pythonanywhere

Tags: flask, global, pythonanywhere

I want to create a SentenceTransformer embedder as a global variable so that I can use in flask methods. As I know from https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/flask_rest_api_tutorial.html, model can be loaded as global variable. But when I use pythonanywhere, something strange happened.

This /print endpoint works properly

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
embedder = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2')

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'

@app.route('/print')
def test_print_embedder():
    return str(embedder)
```

This /print endpoint also works properly.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'

@app.route('/print')
def test_print_embedder():
    embedder = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2')
    output = embedder.encode(['test'],
                  convert_to_tensor=True,
                  device='cpu',
                  batch_size=32
                  )
    return str(output)
```

This /print endpoint does not work properly (the endpoint will just keep loading), why?

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
embedder = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2')

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'

@app.route('/print')
def test_print_embedder():
    output = embedder.encode(['test'],
                  convert_to_tensor=True,
                  device='cpu',
                  batch_size=32
                  )
    return str(output)
```

Comment: Check your error and server logs to see if there is anything in there that can provide a clue about what is going on with the sentence transformer. In particular, look at the difference in the logs between when it's a global and a local variable.